# Django rest framework imagefield optional

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='Images/', 
                            default='/Images/None/No-img.jpg', blank=True,null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    picture = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, 
                                     allow_empty_file=True, use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('id','picture',)     
        read_only_fields=('id')
```

But it's still showing as a required field, I can't make post request with image, is it a bug?

Comment: Did you already try: url = forms.URLField(label='Your website', required=False) aka required=False

Comment: You probably aren't using Forms so maybe in the models.py: null=True?

Comment: I've did try that null=True , it's not making any difference

Comment: @Zargold I think it's bug !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe you should try setting the field `picture` as `required=False` in your serializer.

Since you have defined the `image` field without any `required` parameter, DRF is assuming the default `required` value i.e. `True`. If you don't supply this field during deserialization, DRF will raise an error that `image` field is required.

From the [docs:](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments)

> Normally an error will be raised if a field is not supplied during
>   deserialization. Set to false if this field is not required to be
>   present during deserialization.
>
> **Defaults to `True`.**

```
 class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    picture = serializers.ImageField(required=False, max_length=None, 
                                     allow_empty_file=True, use_url=True)
```

Comment: I've update the my restframework to 3.3 problem solved Thank you for your help

Comment: `extra_kwargs = {'picture': {'required': False}}` also possible like this